# Error with spinner while add new item

Tags: android, spinner, popupwindow

### here is my code:

in it am trying to add more items in the spinner while select one option in the list of spinner items, by the use of popup window...
but am getting error(Force close)while click the "add" at run time...

```
    s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Items);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s1.setAdapter(adapter);
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, 
        View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
        {
 if(index==2)
            {
                    final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(Starttracker.this);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
                    dialog.setTitle("Enter The Item");
                    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

                    final EditText filename=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.filename);
                    filename.setText("");

                    Button d_ok=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.d_ok);
                    Button d_cancel=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.d_cancel);
                    d_ok.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
                        public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent me){

                              String textHolder = "" + filename.getText();
                                 adapter.add(textHolder);
                                 s1.setAdapter(adapter);
                                 dialog.dismiss();
                                 return false;
                        }
                    });
                    d_cancel.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
                        public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent me){
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();

                    return;
                 }
```

pls help me... thanks you friends

Comment: Provide logcat output (you will have some exceptions in there or similar if you had a force close) or provide your full source code (including xml) so people can test it themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer to my question:

```
 d_ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String textHolder = filename.getText().toString();

                    dialog.dismiss();

                    Items.add(textHolder);

                    //  s1.setAdapter(adapter);

                    // notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });
```

thanks a lot all

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it works but try

```
s1.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

instead of

```
s1.setAdapter(adapter);
```